# How can I force zoom-out or min-width on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a largely responsive site, built on Bootstrap 2.3. But one page I need to be zoomed out to fit items that don't work responsively. If I double tap, it zooms out perfectly. But I want to default this way.

[image: skitch]

html:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-width:1024px">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <!-- arbitrary content. point is: zoom out by default, don't crop img -->
            <img src="1024x768.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <!--
                 if min-width is observed, these should be side by side
                 instead of wrapped like responsive normally does
            -->
            <img src="300x768.png"><img src="300x768.png"><img src="300x768.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Note: I'm not trying to disable zoom. I just want to default zoomed out.

I've tried the following without success:

```
1. <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">

2. <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">

3. body { float:left; min-width:1024px; }

4. min-width on all wrapped objects
```

**UPDATE**

Ugh. I was using Google Chrome mobile emulation to debug. Actual mobile device worked fine with html,body {min-width:1024px;}. I threw in  as well to de-responsify some of the content.

Pro-tip: Don't rely on Google Chrome mobile emulation.

Comment: Actually, my skitch isn't entirely accurate. When I zoom out by double-tap, the nav shrinks proportionally instead of remaining full width. Desired result is as pictured, but so far I'm unable to accomplish this.

Comment: Ugh. I was using Google Chrome mobile emulation to debug. Actual mobile device worked fine with `html,body {min-width:1024px;}`. I threw in `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">` as well to de-responsify some of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the meta tag to do so

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

initial-scale ---   The initial zoom when visiting the page. 1.0 does not zoom.

minimum-scale ---   The minimum amount the visitor can zoom on the page. 1.0 does not zoom.

maximum-scale ---   The maximum amount the visitor can zoom on the page. 1.0 does not zoom.

user-scalable ----  Allows the device to zoom in and out. Values are yes or no.

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: Right, but my code above includes that exact meta tag. I've also tried: `"user-scalable=yes"` and `"width=1024"`. Both still result in hidden content upon load. Double-tap reveals.

Comment: Thanks. Will monitor that question as well. So far the `body { float:left; min-width:1024px; }` trick mentioned hasn't helped.